# Attempting to redirect Oracle.DataAccess to Oracle.ManagedDataAccess

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, ado.net

So I have an app with a legacy libraries compiled against Oracle.DataAccess. The app has since been upgraded to use Oracle.ManagedDataAccess but the old libraries are linked against Oracle.DataAccess.

Since both Oracle.DataAccess and Oracle.ManagedDataAccess have the same public key token "89b483f429c47342" I figured I could do an assembly redirect to get around that, but it has not worked.

Here's what I've tried (in the Web.config file of the assembly consuming the legacy libraries):

```
<dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity name="Oracle.DataAccess" publicKeyToken="89b483f429c47342" culture="neutral" />
  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.121.1.0" newVersion="4.121.1.0" />
  <publisherPolicy apply="no" />    
</dependentAssembly>
```

and

```
<dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity name="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess" publicKeyToken="89b483f429c47342" culture="neutral" />
  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.121.1.0" newVersion="4.121.1.0" />
  <publisherPolicy apply="no" />    
</dependentAssembly>
```

Basically what happens is nothing. I keep getting a compile error saying:

> Error CS0012: The type 'Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter' is
>   defined in an assembly that is not referenced. Consider adding a
>   reference to assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess, Version=4.112.2.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342' (CS0012)

The code in question is a method that takes a `OracleParameter` type.

Why would this not be working? Am I misunderstanding what assembly binding redirects are for?

Comment: it seem that it can't find a type in question in your new assembly. Try to use reflector or dotPeek to find `OracleParameter` in it

Comment: Do assembly redirects work if the assembly name has changed?

Comment: Honestly, I have never used this technique. But I used ODP.NET a lot. So, `OracleParameter` is like brother to me

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check the project file for reference of oracle dll and the version of the same. I ran into such an issue and turned recently.

```
<Reference Include="Oracle.DataAccess, Version=4.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342, processorArchitecture=x86">
  <HintPath>..\..\SharedAssemblies\Oracle.DataAccess.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

As you can see, the reference section in my proj file had 4.121.2.0 from the location where the dll was being referred, while the physical file present in the location was of version 4.112.2.0. Once I made this change, I could proceed further.